# Not able to pass EditText field data to textviewfield in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am implementing app like given at:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

In addition to the above given layout. I have added a EditText box on top with show button next to it. Now when I am clicking on Show button, I am passing the text value present in EditTextbox i.e. in EditTextbox "Great" is written, so I am modifiying it to Tab1-Great, Tab2-Great and passing it to the viewPager function and setting it to the textview in respective tabs and notifying the change. But the information is not getting updated in the textview in different tabs.

Please guide.

Mainactivity relevant code:

''' pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount(), mEdit.getText().toString());
viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
'''
PageAdapter relvant code:

'''
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
switch(position)
{
case 0:
ftb1 = new ftab1(mEdit);
return ftb1;
}
}
'''

Tab code:
'''Public class ftab1 extends Fragment {

```
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private static String passedparam="Default";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;



public ftab1(String searchText) {
    
        passedparam = locapassedparam;

   }


// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ftab1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ftab1 fragment = new ftab1(passedparam);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftab1, container,  false);

    //textview related code


   return myView;
}
```

}'''

Answer (score 0):

you should at least post a picture or your code
in tablayout eachtab is a fragment so if you want to pass a string between fragments u can use intent or use interface(trigger when use press the button)
once you passed the variable you can simply set it to the textview at "onTabSelected" method. there are a lots of tutorial, just search

Comment: I have edited my question to add the code. Whereas OnTabSelected I am using the following code:

'''
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
'''